# How to make Vue.js app with routing work in Heroku?

Tags: express, heroku, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I followed [this article](http://www.travisluong.com/how-to-deploy-a-vue-js-app-to-heroku/) to deploy the app to heroku. It works at a minimal level.

The app utilizes vue-router. The common thing about single app application is that routing doesn't work if we don't to home page first to bootstrap the framework.

Since I am using Express.js to create a server for the app, which doesn't have a backend, I created a wildcard route to server the index.html to all routes. So if a user entered /some-route, express.js servers the index.html which will bootstrap the framework, then it should work out how to serve components to that route.

server.js

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>front</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/scottjehl/picturefill/3.0.2/dist/picturefill.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`Server.js` does it job. The index.html is sent to every route. But the page is blank because `index.html` doesn't have the script (like, dist/app.js) to bootstrap the vue.js framework.

The thing is, I don't need the script if I just go to the root route. Everything works even though `index.html` doesn't have built app.js script. It doesn't work if I go to other routes. The page is blank.

So I thought, maybe I should add that built script to index.html manually. However, when Heroku build the app, every built file has a version number, like this:

```
remote:        > node build/build.js
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        Starting to optimize CSS...
remote:        Processing static/css/app.0b5f04e14ffb7ccea3fa9f8f33ffbb29.css...
remote:        Processed static/css/app.0b5f04e14ffb7ccea3fa9f8f33ffbb29.css, before: 2008, after: 1940, ratio: 96.61%
remote:        Hash: f26c9282218b6a3fa3a5
remote:        Version: webpack 2.4.1
remote:        Time: 12380ms
remote:        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
remote:        static/js/app.629caa4c18bbb9036878.js  21.1 kB       0  [emitted]  app
remote:        static/js/vendor.32e38f7fbd283989a03f.js   199 kB       1  [emitted]  vendor
remote:        static/js/manifest.d0cfe9987077f3610ffd.js   1.5 kB       2  [emitted]  manifest
remote:        static/css/app.0b5f04e14ffb7ccea3fa9f8f33ffbb29.css  1.94 kB       0  [emitted]  app
remote:        static/js/app.629caa4c18bbb9036878.js.map    99 kB       0  [emitted]  app
remote:        static/css/app.0b5f04e14ffb7ccea3fa9f8f33ffbb29.css.map   4.7 kB       0  [emitted]  app
remote:        static/js/vendor.32e38f7fbd283989a03f.js.map  2.24 MB       1  [emitted]  vendor
remote:        static/js/manifest.d0cfe9987077f3610ffd.js.map  14.4 kB       2  [emitted]  manifest
remote:        index.html  1.45 kB          [emitted]
remote:        
remote:        Build complete.
```

So I can't just add `static/js/app.js` to index.html.

So now I am stuck.

1. Why the vue.js app works when I go the root route even though `index.html` doesn't contain the built app script?
2. How to handle routing in production, in this caes, Heroku, so that users don't need to go to root route first to bootstrap the framework. They could just go to /some-route and everything should work.

Comment: The server needs to redirect all routing requests to `index.html` so the SPA can handle routing. But you need to let non-routing requests (like static assets and api calls) go thru to the server. You seem to already know this based on the `server.js` file, so i don't know what you don't understand about routing.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `server.js` file that should work for you:

```js
var express = require('express')
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback')
var path = require('path')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')


var app = express()

// Use a fallback for non-root routes (required for Vue router)
//   NOTE: History fallback must be "used" before the static serving middleware!
app.use(history({
    // OPTIONAL: Includes more verbose logging
    verbose: true
}))

// Serve static assets from the build files (images, etc)
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')))

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started at http://localhost:5000')
})
```

Comment: Note that is imperative that the `connect-history-api-fallback` **preceedes** the `serve-static` middleware!

Comment: Thanks @Kendall, this was my issue as I had serve-static as first option.

Answer (score 1):

I now use https://nuxtjs.org/ to handle server side rendering. And I don't need to worry about routing.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you. I have used this script to deploy my blog in Heroku written by Vue

```
const express = require("express");
const serveStatic = require("serve-static");
const path = require("path");
const compression = require("compression"); // <-- import this library
const app = express();

// use compression
app.use(compression()); // <-- use the library

//here we are configuring dist to serve app files
app.use("/", serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, "/dist")));

// this * route is to serve project on different page routes except root `/`
app.get(/.*/, function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/dist/index.html"));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port);
console.log(`app is listening on port: ${port}`);
```

I use `app.get(/.*/, function(req, res)` instead of `app.get('/*', function (req, res)`

Answer (score 0):

An Update on this. If you are deploying an SPA app on Heroku, you need to create and configure a ***static.json*** file on your route folder having:

```
{
    "root": "./dist",
    "routes": {
        "/assets/*": "/assets/",
        "/**": "index.html"
    }
}
```

... routes configures the rewriting rule. This has to do with buildpack configuration but i need to read more about it to give a complete answer.